# Cannot root phone by installing superuser.zip CWM v6.0.5.1 Stable

Tags: adb, root-access

Xiaomi redmi 2 runs MIUI 6.2.4.0(KHJCNBK)

In order to install CWM, I downloaded both the adb and fastboot, I extracted `recovery.img` in the folder, together with them. I entered fastboot mode.

Then, in fastboot I ran:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

fastboot reboot
```

Now I booted CWM into recovery. It I ran this superuser file, which matches my phone model. It installed, had `done!` at the end:

[image]
 However, when I exit the menu it asks me whether to root the phone ( with `root access is missing` at the top ), I tried both yes/no, it reboots, but phone is still not rooted. What's the issue here?

Comment: Its rooted, and that prompt (it appears only when the supersu isnt properly installed, like its binaries). So, there might be some problem with supersu binaries. I suggest you turn on phone and then verify root and supersu status. Get some app from play store like root checker and see how that does too

Comment: Have you tried booting your device normally and running the SuperUser app? As Jaskaranbir suggests, it might need to update some of its binaries (especially the `su` binary requires this sometimes). If you do so, keep your eyes open for any possible error messages and, if there are some, [edit] your question and include them. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Just installed the .apk from superuserdownload.com. Runs fine, but the "apps" tab is empty. My objective is to clear factory apps, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did succesfully installed the superuser framework but you need to install SuperSu what controls everything. Follow steps below to successfully install SuperSu:

1. Download SuperSu from the play store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu).
2. Open SuperSu and you should see something like this:

[image: update su binary]

<sub>Screenshot - Update SU binary (Click to enlarge)</sub>

3. Click continue.
4. Click normal. (If you see message for more then 5 minutes then reboot and try the other option)
5. Reboot your phone and now you should be rooted. Check it with a root checker app like this:

[image: root check, success]

<sub>ScreenShot - Root check, Success (Click to enlarge)</sub>

6. Consider purchasing the pro version to support the developer [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu.pro).

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: @Firelord I added more info.

Comment: I get `there is no SU binary installed, and SuperSU cannot install it` When attempting to run the app.

Comment: @StevenHaen Then there was a problem installing the SU binary, you should reinstall the su binary and select yes when it gives the message yourbphone may not be rooted etc. Then follow my steps again.

Comment: When I click `normal` it spits back `update failed`. When I try to use my CWM it displays `will try to reboot device` and then nothing happens.

Comment: Then reboot your device and try again

Comment: Simply flash this
[SuperSu](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip?retrieve_file=1)

And then reboot. In case SUperSu app doesnt show, install from play store. Thats all